# Fourier transform as an integral on $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

We often define Fourier transform $\mathcal F$ on $L^2$ by continuously extending it from $L^1$ or the Swartz space $\mathcal S$. There are of course other ways to do it.

**Note:** by "integral" I am referring to the Lebesgue integral.

But now, I am interested in the **convergence** of the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x) e^{-i\langle x, \xi\rangle} dx 
$$
itself. Even if the function $f$ is not in $L^1$, this integral could converge, sometimes for almost every $\xi$. For example, if we pick a real-valued function $g(x)$ that is not $L^1$ but $L^2$, then the Fourier transform integral of $g(x)e^{i\langle x,\xi_0 \rangle}$ is undefined when $\xi=\xi_0$, but is defined for other values of $\xi$.

**Does there exists a function $f\in L^2 (\mathbb R)$ such that the integral**
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-ix \xi} dx
$$
**diverges for $\xi$ on a set of non-zero measure?**

Comment: In which sense do you understand the convergence of the integral?

Comment: @PhoemueX Just the usual Lebesgue integral.

Comment: But a function is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable (given that $f$ is measurable). The phase factor does not change the absolute value. Thus, $f$ needs to be integrable itself.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.  The integral only exists (in the $L^1(\mathbb R)$ sense) when $f \in L^1$ and there are plenty of $L^2$ functions that are not $L^1$.  On the other hand, defined as a limiting process, the Fourier transform exists for all $f \in L^2$ , so the integral will exist as a limit.

Answer (score 1):

The inversion integral for $f\in L^2$ converges in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. That is,
$$
           \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}\hat{f}(s)e^{-isx}ds-f\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=0.
$$
You can choose a subsequence that converges pointwise a.e. to $f$.